# How do I stop content being cut off inside a div

Tags: html, css

HI i have a two column layout on this site http://stylrs.com/press/ however animated content from the column divs gets cut off if it exceeds the size of the div. I cannot figure out why. Could someone please help?

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML and CSS in the question so that we can reproduce the error. Otherwise, this question risks being closed.

Comment: @tylerH I cannot reproduce the error outside of the website link above

Comment: This is very helpful if you can provide your html and css code. However I think Daerst's answer is correct and can solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `overflow: hidden` property from `#container` style

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`div`s have a property [`overflow`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp). It is used to control the behaviour of content exceeding the `div`'s dimensions. Though this property is set to `visible` by default, try setting it explicitly and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

your `#container` element has an `overflow:hidden` on it. You need to remove that to stop it from cutting off on the left side. It doesn't look like removing the overflow property on it does anything negative, even when you resize it down, but it might be used as a clearfix, so you may need to tend to that if you see clearfix issues after removing.